# How to compare number of incidents in different geographical areas when they have different population size?

Tags: normalization, population, differences, geography

I'm trying to make comparisons between number of incidents that happened in different zip codes. The goal is to figure out whether those incidents happen more frequently in certain areas than others. The problem is that some zip codes are more populated than others and we would expect to see more incidents in more populated areas. I am trying to find a way to normalize the data to control for difference in population size and thus make accurate comparisons between areas that have different population sizes. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Can you say a bit more about the context? Do the zip codes form part of larger areas for which you have some moderator variable which you wish to model?

Comment: You could use poisson regression with $\log(\text{Pop Size})$ as an offset.